# Excel VBA: Loop through two columns in sheet1, look for specific names, paste rows with matching value to sheet2

Tags: excel, vba

**Context:** New to VBA

**Task:** I have a contact list in Worksheet1 which contains columns: LastName, FirstName, email, phone #, and several more. I have a second contact list in Worksheet2 (formatted exactly the same) which contains approximately 500 of the 1,000 names found in the Worksheet1 contact list BUT with updated contact information (email, phone #, etc.). I'm trying to write code to find which names are in both worksheets, and for those names, copy the email, phone#, etc. from Worksheet2 (updated information) and paste it into the corresponding location in Worksheet2.

**Code:** This is what I have so far. It does not work.

```
 Sub UpdateContacts()

 Dim Reference As String
 Dim Range As Range
 Dim ContactList As Worksheet
 Dim UpdatedContacts As Worksheet

 ContactList = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Contact List")
 UpdatedContacts = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Updated Contacts")

 Reference = ContactList.Range("B5", "C5").Value

 j = 5

 For i = 5 To UpdatedContacts.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

      If UpdatedContacts.Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 3)).Value = Reference Then
           UpdatedContacts.Range(Cells(i, 4), Cells(i, 17)).Copy _
           Destination:=ContactList.Range(Cells(j, 4), Cells(j, 17))
           j = j + 1
      End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: this can be done without VBA and worksheet formulas. Are you okay with that solution? Is this a one-time thing, or will it need to be processed over and over again?

Comment: How would you execute without VBA? I expect to have to continually update certain contacts.

Comment: if you have a new contacts sheet dump, you can place that in `sheet2` as a template, then have a 3rd sheet all formula based that holds all the names in sheet1 and then has formulas to look up the names in sheet2 and if they exist pull the data from there, otherwise pull it from sheet1. Then paste sheet 3 as values over sheet1 for full current list. Once it's its set up, to update it is basically 2 pastes of data. Very quick.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working solution with some minor improvements such as `Option Explicit`, fully qualified references at all times, `Option Compare Text` to ignore capital letters when comparing the names, `Trim` to ignore possible leading or trailing spaces, and creating another outer loop to do the comparison for all names on `shtContactList`:

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Sub UpdateContacts()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rngCell As Range
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim strReference As String
Dim shtContactList As Worksheet
Dim shtUpdatedContacts As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Select Case ws.Name
        Case "Contact List"
            Set shtContactList = ws
        Case "Updated Contacts"
            Set shtUpdatedContacts = ws
        Case Else
            Debug.Print ws.Name
    End Select
Next ws
If shtContactList Is Nothing Or shtUpdatedContacts Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "One or more required sheet(s) were not found." & Chr(10) & "Aborting..."
    Exit Sub
End If

For j = 5 To shtContactList.Cells(shtContactList.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    strReference = Trim(shtContactList.Cells(j, 2).Value2) & ", " & Trim(shtContactList.Cells(j, 3).Value2)
    For i = 5 To shtUpdatedContacts.Cells(shtUpdatedContacts.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If Trim(shtUpdatedContacts.Cells(i, 2).Value2) & ", " & Trim(shtUpdatedContacts.Cells(i, 3).Value2) = strReference Then
            shtUpdatedContacts.Range(shtUpdatedContacts.Cells(i, 4), shtUpdatedContacts.Cells(i, 17)).Copy _
                Destination:=shtContactList.Range(shtContactList.Cells(j, 4), shtContactList.Cells(j, 17))
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next i
Next j

End Sub
```

If the code is running slow you might want to consider using an array: (1) put the entire sheet `shtUpdatedContacts` into an array as well as the sheet `shtContactList` and (2) then make the search / comparison there. (3) Finally, paste the updates array back to sheet `shtContactList`.

Comment: Thanks Ralph, I appreciate the help. I ran this code but nothing happened. I will continue reviewing.